# Uploading Files in Angular with Spring Boot: Facing 500 Internal Error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, file-upload, error-handling, postman

I'm a nooby in Angular and Spring Boot, and I'm currently working on a project that involves uploading files. I've set up the backend using Spring Boot and the frontend using Angular, but I'm encountering an issue with the file upload process. i tested the backeend with postman it all goes well by but not with the connection with the front and it retun 500 internal server error

here is a photo with the error from the console:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2297.png)

Spring boot Controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> uploadFiles(@RequestParam("files")List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles) throws IOException {
        List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();
        for(MultipartFile file : multipartFiles) {
            String filename = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
            Path fileStorage = get(DIRECTORY, filename).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
            copy(file.getInputStream(), fileStorage, REPLACE_EXISTING);
            filenames.add(filename);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(filenames);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="upload-box">
  <form class="form-inline" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="icon">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-2x fa-file-arrow-up"></i>
        <p>Select your PDF file or drop it here</p>
      </div>
      <input class="select" type="file" class="form-control" id="pdfile" placeholder="file" accept="application/pdf" name="pdfFile"(change)="onSelectFile($event)" multiple>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Upload Pdf" (click)="uploadFile()">
    </div>
    
  </form>
</div>
```

TS:

```
 onSelectFile(event: any): void {
    this.selectedFiles= event.target?.files;

    
  }

  uploadFile()  {
    if (this.selectedFiles.length == 0) {
      console.log('No files selected.');
      return;
    }
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const file of this.selectedFiles) {
      formData.append('files', file);
    }

    this.dataService.upload(formData).subscribe(
      event => {
        console.log(event);
        this.reportProgress(event);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Service:

```
  uploadFile(files: File) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('files', files, files.name);
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      })
      
    };

    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl2 + 'file/upload', formData, httpOptions);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the headers, that worked out for me, also prepare the form data inside the service itself just once.

component

```
   uploadFile()  {
    if (this.selectedFiles.length == 0) {
      console.log('No files selected.');
      return;
    }

    this.dataService.upload(this.selectedFiles).subscribe(
      event => {
        console.log(event);
        this.reportProgress(event);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
```

service

```
 uploadFile(files: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    files.forEach((file: any) => {
        formData.append('files', file, file.name);
    });
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: {}      
    };

    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl2 + 'file/upload', formData, httpOptions);
  }
```

Comment: @NourBenHadjAbdallah Does this answer resolve your issue?